# Como listar todos os posts em uma pagina personalizada? WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Bem, criei uma pagina personalizada onde preciso que ela retorne **todos** os posts que tem cadastrado no site, como se fosse a home.
Tentei fazer da forma normal, criando uma pagina personalizada e atribuindo a elá o mesmo código que se encontra na `index.php`, porem quando eu tento listar todos os posts ele apenas me retorna a pagina como se fosse uma pagina de publicação...

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Novos Posts
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div class="cont_marg">
    <div class="pad_sd">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <ul class="lista-filmes">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE); ?>
                    <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <div class="titulo-box open-sans">
                            <h2 class="titulo-box-link">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="capa">
                            <div class="fluccs">
                                <div class="boxxer"><?php echo $my_meta['durat']; ?>min</div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="absolute-capa no-text effect"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(158,226)); ?>
                            <div class="flutuador" style="background:none;">
                                <div class="audioy"><?php echo the_qualt($my_meta['qualt']); ?></div>
                                <div class="anolanc"><?php echo $my_meta['ano']; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="views"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?> visitas</div>
                    </li><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php post_pagination();?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .pad_sd -->
</div><!-- .cont_marg -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Sabe quando nos criamos uma pagina personalizada? Pronto só que eu não quero que essa pagina seja um post, quero que ela me retorne todos os posts que já tenho, mas ela só me retornou o que ela pesa ser o dela mesmo. Entenderam??

Answer (score 2):

Entendi. Você quer que uma página, através do *loop* no seu template, mostre todos os *posts* que você tem cadastrados, e não o texto da página.

Isso está acontecendo porque você está usando o *loop* padrão, que acessa a global `WP_Query`. Como o seu ambiente é uma página, o `WP` entende que deve, no *loop*, fazer o display daquele post (i.e., a página na qual você está). Para contornar o problema, você pode criar uma nova instância da consulta, especificando a sua necessidade, e não deixando a cargo do `WP`. Retirado do [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage):

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Para forçar que essa nova consulta busque por posts (`post_type => post`), você deve inicializar o parâmetro `$args` da seguinte maneira

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
)
```

Ou ainda, montar a consulta como

```
$the_query = new WP_Query ( array( 'post_type'=>'post' ) );
```

O Codex tem todos os parâmetros que o construtor da `WP_Query` pode receber. Basicamente, eles filtram o resultado da consulta. Do jeito que está, ela vai resgatar todos os *posts* do tipo *post*.

Obviamente, você deve alterar esta lógica para atender o seu *mark-up*. Mas, basicamente, você apenas invoca os métodos `have_posts()` e afins a partir do seu novo objeto, e não do global.

Comment: Olá. Excelente colocação. Gostaria de pedir uma complementação: Como eu faria para exibis no loop, apenas os posts de uma determinada categoria? Imagino que seria algo assim:

```
  $the_query = new WP_Query ( array( 'post_type'=>'post', 'category' => 'any_category' ) ); 

```

Seria isso?

Comment: @LucianoBezerra o caminho é esse. Você pode ver os parâmetros de categoria [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). De maneira abrangente, você poderia fazer `$the_query = new WP_Query ( array( 'post_type'=>'post', 'category_name' => 'minha_categoria' ) );`