# Organizar informações em ordem alfabetica - Html/JavaScript ou Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Seguinte,

Tenho um site em `wordpress`, criei uma página dentro desse site e nessa página vou ter uma lista de empresas mais ou menos assim:

> **Empresa A** - (Nome da empresa)
>
> - Dados da empresas (Esses dados vão ficar ocultos, vão aparecer quando o usuário clicar no nome da empresa).
>
> **Empresa B**
>
> **Empresa C**

Eu vou alimentar essa lista manualmente, então pode ter dia que vou adicionar empresa que começa com X no outro dia empresa que começa com B e por ai vai.

É possível fazer uma organização automática via javascript, onde eu colocasse uma empresa em baixo da outra independente da letra inicial do nome dela e quando for pro ar ir em ordem alfabética?

Não sei se ficou muito claro a dúvida, mas resumindo quero saber como organizar uma lista automáticamente em ordem alfabética.

Obrigado.

---

Pessoal, como estou usando `wordpress` optei por usar `custom post type` conforme os colegas sugeriram nas respostas, legal criei o `post type` esta funcionando certinho, mas ainda esta um pouco complicado a parte de organizá-los em ordem alfabética, estava lendo o codex o que é um pouco alias muito complicado PRA MIM, e la fala que a função query esta no arquivo query.php, porem no meu tema não tem esse arquivo. Dei uma olhada nos arquivos functions.php e também não achei nada de query, qual o arquivo exato devo "mexer"?

Comment: se cada empresa for um post, basta você ordenar o loop, não?

Comment: Não será um post cada empresa, elas vão estar todas na mesma pagina, so vou esconder as infos de cada uma que so vai aparecer se o usuario clicar sobre ela...  Mas a lista de empresas vão ficar todas na mesma pagina uma em baixo da outra igual no exemplo do post.

Comment: Sim, mas pq não tornar cada empresa um post, ou um custom post? Facilita (e muito) a sua vida. Ordenação de posts o wp faz sozinho, não precisa reinventar a roda.

Comment: Entendo, realmente iria me ajudar muito, vou ter que ler sobre custom post então para tentar fazer, tem algum exemplo ou referencia que eu possa dar uma olhada?  obrigado. @CaioFelipePereira

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types codex sempre salvando vidas. Eu também dei [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104223/como-listar-todos-os-posts-em-uma-pagina-personalizada-wordpress/104517#104517) uma vez que talvez possa te dar uma certa luz. Leia sobre a [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) também

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira ok vlw obrigado.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira desculpa encher o saco de novo, editei a pergunta se puder dar uma olhada. vlw obrigado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34962/discussion-between-caio-felipe-pereira-and-erick).

Answer (score 1):

Já que você está usando Wordpress, não poderia inserir essas empresas como um custom post type? Depois é só inserir um loop na página para exibir as empresas com o argumento de ordem alfabética.

Minha resposta vai continuar incompleta, mas para você se basear, o código para criar um custom post do tipo empresa seria parecido com esse:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'thinkup_widgets_init' );
register_post_type('empresas', array(
'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'empresas' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Ver empresas' ),
            'add_new' => __('Novo empresas'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar novo empresas'),
            'edit_item' => __('Editar empresas'),
            'new_item' => __('Novo empresas'),
            'view_item' => __('Visualizar empresas'),
            'search_items' => __('Pesquisar empresas')
),
'menu_position' => 3,
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'empresas'),
'show_ui' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' , 'editor', 'excerpt'  )
)
);
```

Irá aparecer um novo tipo de Post no seu painel, adicione as empresas lá. E para puxar em um loop essas empresas, parte do código do argumento para ordem alfabética (orderby) seria mais ou menos assim:

```
$args = array(

  'post_type' => array('empresas'),
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
   'orderby' => 'name',
   );
```

Espero que dê para ter uma ideia sobre o que fazer.

Comment: Seria uma boa e mais facil, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso... É possível através de um formulário eu inserir essas infos dentro da pagina?

Comment: Po ajudou sim, estou vendo alguns videos aqui sobre ,  esse código deve ser inserido no functions.php?   Vou fuçando aqui para entrar melhor como funciona e conforme surgir dúvidas post aqui no stack ... vlw obrigado.

Comment: Sim, o primeiro código vai no functions.php que tem a função de criar esse novo tipo de Post no seu painel, para poder inserir as empresas por lá. Já o segundo código seria para você exibir as empresas na página que quiser, mas falta parte do código, pesquise no google por "loop custom post type".

Comment: Blz vou criar aqui e ver o que consigo vlwww

Comment: Só uma duvida, criando o post type eu consigo imprimir cada "item" que eu cadastrar dentro da minha pagina?  e atraves do loop  eu ordeno os itens dentro da pagina é isso? correto?

Comment: @Erick essa resposta está no caminho certo, mas sugiro que você leia um pouco sobre o funcionamento do WP

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira blzz to tentando, fiz o post type ja consigo cadastrar, agora vou para o proximo passo que e tentar exibir na pagina criada! =D vlw

Comment: qualquer coisa, edita a sua pergunta e a gente tenta responder o problema

Answer (score -2):

Essa é uma forma de ordenação para array em javascript.

```html
var items = [
  { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
  { name: 'And', value: 45 },
  { name: 'The', value: -12 },
  { name: 'Magnetic' },
  { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
];
items.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: Se você vai usar o código dos outros para dar um exemplo tente pesquisar melhor e colocar a referencia.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
Fora que esse script não atende o que a pergunta pede.